# Get Django model row results

Tags: javascript, html, json, django, api

Well My first ever question was put on hold so lets try again...
**I'm a real beginner at all of this** 
I'm creating a HR webapp. I can put data into the db, I can even get a few parts to dynamically populate drop down items. 
What I am now trying to do is get items from the model to populate a table.

these items will come from the below model.

```
class Resource(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    preferred_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    employstatus = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    employer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    role = models.ForeignKey('Role')
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location')
    workphone = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    mobile_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    archived = models.BooleanField()
```

Below is the part of the api I am trying to write to take out the correct parts.

In essence what I am trying to do is show this data as a result of a search function that will come later. 
The search will be for surname. It will show the info below and using the pk as a reference id I can get it to open a html page and pull all of the data from that person and populate their page.
The data is then represented with js onto a html table.

```
def searchres(request):
    data = {'Resource':[]}

    reslist = []
    for r in Resource.object.all():
            t = (r.pk, r.last_name, r.preferred_name, r.employer, r.location, r.role)
            reslist.append(t)

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

this is the table to populate

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered"id='serres' >
    <thead>
      <tr>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Preferred Name</th>
    <th>Employer</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Role</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr onclick="document.location = '/Personnel/results.html?id=10';">
  </table>
</div>
```

Could I have some help with the python part of getting a dictionary with the required info packed up so I can get the js to populate the table please.

so it needs to look like this ???

```
def searchres(request):
        data = {'Resource':[]}
        data['Resource'] = reslist

        reslist = []
        for r in Resource.object.all():
                t = (r.pk, r.last_name, r.preferred_name, r.employer, r.location, r.role)
                 reslist.append(t)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: I thought you had everything, just give your `reslist` to the data dict and you are done, `data['Resource'] = reslist`, right? You might need to convert some foreign key to a string, like `location` and `role`.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code (apart from the fact that you never add reslist to the data dict)?

Comment: Well as it say's above I am very new to this and this is the first thing I have ever tried to make. it was more a case of not understanding why what I had wasn't working. And any advice on how to do something or make the existing code more streamlined would be beneficial so I can improve my knowledge and understanding of how it works to save me asking dumb questions again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple different things: 1st,  as @Shang Wang said, you need to give your reslist to the data dict before you return it as a JSON. Its not completely clear how you want to have the data appended though, because you have singular "Resource" but that doesn't really make sense. I also don't know why you are creating an intermediary object "reslist" at all. I'm going to guess that you want something like this:

```
data = {"Resources":[]}
for r in Resource.object.all():
        t={
           "pk":r.pk, 
           "last_name":r.last_name,
           "preferred_name":r.preferred_name, 
           "employer":r.employer,
           "location":r.location, 
           "role":r.role
       }
        data["Resources"].append(t)
```

where "Resources" is a list of Resource dictionaries. I would think it would be more useful to create a dictionary in t than a tuple, the way you're doing, because then later when you use your JSON object in the javascript you can do:

```
data["Resources"][0]["last_name"]
```

instead of

```
data["Resources"][0][1]
```

Just seems more intuitive to me.

Second,

```
for r in Resource.object.all():
```

should be

```
for r in Resource.objects.all():
```

Note the "s" for plural "objects".

Comment: Ahh well that would probably be because I'm not 100% on what I'm doing and cobbling bits I have found together so thank you @Isaac Ray 
I still have a great deal to do on it, this is my first Django app.
I'm glad my rather long winded way of explaining what I needed didn't get lost in translation.